# многострочные значения в XML

Tags: delphi, xml, xmlparser

Как через стандартный XMLDocument записать многострочныое значение в XML файл? 
И вообще поддерживается ли это форматом XML?
т.е. есть в XML файле следующий фрагмент:

```
...
<node1>
    <node2>
        val=3
        pos=10,11,23
        accsess
    </node2>
</node1>
...
```

1. node2 можно как-то считать стандартными средствами через XMLDocument или только самостаятельно парсить?
   Я считывал так:

   Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(FileName);

   Node := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('node2')

Потом загонял в TMemIniFile и читал оттуда, как значения ini файла, но сдаётся мне, это можно сделать без извращений, т.к. отступы в дереве добавляются автоматически, опцией Doc.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent] и сколько там вначале пробелов должно быть, чтобы это выглядело хорошо, неизвестно.
Отсюда вытекает следующий вопрос:

2. как после изменений эту секцию записать назад?

Comment: Отступы внутри тега не добавляются автоматически. Даже после форматирования строки `pos=` и `accsess` должны начинаться с первой позиции новой строки. Ну разве что принудительно для каждой из них будут добавлены лидирующие пробелы. И что означает "считать стандартными средствами"? node2 получен, его содержимое доступно через `Node.Text`, а что внутри этого текста - это уже не забота xml.

Comment: @kami да, это получается просто текст внутри... и да, этот класс при активации этой опции добавляет лидирующие пробелы. Я уже реализовал решение для моего случая. Не красиво, но работает